# Создание Private database в CloudKit dashboard

Tags: ios

Как создать Private database в CloudKit dashboard? Доступна только Public database. Новый веб-интерфейс очень запутанный.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что после создания аккаунта разработчика, я не заходил в iCloud под этой учетной записью. Сейчас появилась Private database.